# Trying to input ads code in my website but there is error in this code can someone fix please

Tags: javascript, ads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    atOptions = {
        'key' : '4acc9ecf15520c3ad2d27837af408a5f',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 50,
        'width' : 320,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.effectivedisplayformats.com/4acc9ecf15520c3ad2d27837af408a5f/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea for you to use `document.write` in inline JavaScript (especially those in `<body>`) because it'll overwrite the `<script>` itself. Perhaps you can create an element and change its `innerHTML`, or you can put it into `<head>` and use `<body onload>`.

Answer (score 0):

SYNC

atOptions = {
        'key' : '0b7a536d7e5c01f0c963a75a71b7ca74',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 250,
        'width' : 300,
        'params' : {}
    };
    document.write('');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).